# Android Fragments - Should we really save state?

Tags: android, save, fragment, instance, state

I have implemented a simple activity with this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment_1.Operations{

Fragment_1 fragment_1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragmentactivity);
    fragment_1=(Fragment_1)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_1");
}
//called on buttonclick, fired from a button existing in R.layout.fragmentactivity
public void createFragment(View view){

    if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_1")==null){

        fragment_1=new Fragment_1();

        FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        transaction.add(R.id.fragmentactt,fragment_1,"fragment_1");
        transaction.commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
    }
    else{

        fragment_1=(Fragment_1)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_1");
    }

    //Simply adding item to the listview contained in fragment_1.
    fragment_1.add("Project #1");
    fragment_1.add("Project #2");
    fragment_1.add("Project #3");
}

    //callback of interface "Operations"
    @Override
    public void buttonClicked() {

        FragmentTransaction transaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (fragment_1.isAdded()){

            transaction.remove(fragment_1);
            //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the doubt came from the fact that no "onSaveInstanceState" needed to be implemented, everything got "saved" without any problems.

So, why should i use putfragment and getFragment? Do these methods need to be called in order to avoid that, when OS kills app process, they would be lost? This is the only reason i can imagine to force onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activity and fragment lifecycles are linked so when any callback method such as *onResume* is called for the activity, it is called for the fragment too.

*putFragment* and *getFragment* help the activity to manage its fragment child's lifecycle. The activity also has to save instance state.

In order to be activity independant, a fragment can manage his own instance state.

Comment: Exactly as i thought, i manage fragment_1 in his own "onSaveInstanceState" and "onCreateView"..

So this prevents my state from being lost, right? i could not use putFragment and getFragment as long as i manage it in fragments?

Comment: You are right. A fragment should always be activity independant.

Comment: If you really want to save the instance of your fragment, I suggest you to use "newIstance " method,  is a best practice to do that